# Can we recognise '%' & 'px' in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, width

When reading width of DIV section, the result comes in %. But, I want to convert it in pixel value. How is it possible ?

I have a class "h" defined in my html. It has width="100%". It's parent div has width="69%".

```
width = ($(this).find('.h').width())
```

So actually the width is not window.width() but it is 69% of it. I want it in pixel !!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of reading the css use [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/), in the case the div isn't visible (which appears to be the case from your previous answer), show it get the width and hide it, like this:

```
var width = $("#div").show().width(); $('#div").hide();
```

since the UI thread won't update until this is done...the user won't see it.  Make sure [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) is what you're after though (e.g. do you want margins or not?)  There are other dimension methods if you do/don't want padding/margins, [you can find them here](http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/).

Comment: Quick Draw Craver beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

From what I read on the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/width/) , you can use .width() in jQuery to return a unitless pixel value that can be used for mathematical calculations.

Example:

```
$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```

Click the link and look at the demo at the bottom of the first function. I think it's your answer.